# Spectrum of the sum of matrices

Tags: graph-theory

I have an $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ such that:

$$A = J_n + (k-1)I_n$$

$I_n$ being the identity matrix and $J_n$ the all-$1$ matrix.

The spectra of those matrices are as follow:

$$Spec(J_n) = (k^2 -k +1)^1(0)^{n-1}$$
and
$$Spec((k-1)I_n) = (k-1)^n$$

I don't understand why I then have

$$Spec(A) = (k^2)^1(k-1)^{n-1}$$

Is there a formula for $Spec(A+B)$ that I am missing?

Comment: If $p(t)$ is a polynomial then the eigenvalues of $p(M)$ are given by the values of $p$ on the eigenvalues of $M$. Take $p(t)$ to be $t+k-1$ and $M=J$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\dim\ker J_n=n-1$ hence $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$ and the last eigenvalue is $\mathrm{tr}(J_n)=n$ where  $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ denote the trace of the matrix $A$ so 
$$\mathrm{spectrum}(J_n)=\{0,\ldots,0,n\}$$
and obviously we have
$$\mathrm{spectrum}((k-1)I_n)=\{k-1,\ldots,k-1\}$$
so we can conclude that
$$\mathrm{spectrum}(J_n+(k-1)I_n)=\{k-1,\ldots,k-1,k+n-1\}$$

**Remark** If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices which conmmute i.e. $AB=BA$ then they are triangularizable over $\mathbb C$ (*or if it's possible diagonalizable*) in the same basis and in this case we have
$$\mathrm{spectrum}(A+B)=\{\lambda_i+\mu_i,\quad i=1,\ldots,n\}$$
where $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Comment: Maybe a noob question, but where does the ordering on the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ come from? (Referring to the last part of your answer)